# Laravel row creation fillable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to create a key for every new insert in an eloquent model(not nullable). This key should not be in the `$fillable` array because it should not be mass assigned or changed at all. I tried this in the model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::creating(function ($object) {
       $object->key = md5(uniqid("CT", true));
    });
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work as i get an exception saying

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column 'key'...

Comment: What's the modal look like?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create a new instance of the object in the controller and then assing the value you need manually, in the nex example I specify the user ID of a ticket outside of the mass assignment

The model that I use looks like this

```
class TicketComment extends Entity
{
    protected $fillable = ['comment', 'link'];

    /**
     * Return the ticket of the given comment.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function ticket()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::getClass());
    }

    /**
     * Return the user of the given comment.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::getClass());
    }
}
```

And this is the method that saves the comment, note how I added the user ID

```
public function submit($id, Request $request, Guard $auth)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comment' => 'required|max:250',
        'link' => 'url'
    ]);

    $comment = new TicketComment($request->all());
    $comment->user_id = $auth->id();

    $ticket = Ticket::findOrFail($id);
    $ticket->comments()->save($comment);

    session()->flash('success', 'Your comment has been saved successfully');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go

`App\Test.php` model

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function getNewId()
    {
        return md5(uniqid("CT", true));
    }

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->{$model->getKeyName()} = $model->getNewId();
        });
    }
}
```

Migration for the `test` table

```
class CreateTestTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('test', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary('id');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('test');
    }
}
```

Let's test it with `tinker`

```
>>> $a = App\Test::create([]);
=>  {
       id: "afedc2972f980d20ca95b556a93c0db1",
       updated_at: "2015-08-07 15:24:24",
       created_at: "2015-08-07 15:24:24"
   }
>>>
```